# Magento 2 : Adding custom header label and link

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3, headerlink

I want to know how to add  custom link to the header panel that should be manageable from back-end. so that the person trying to change the value can easily change it without any coding knowledge

I have tried it with module and it successfully worked using following code:-

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">

 <block class="Learning\Module\Block\Link" name="custom-header-link">
     
            <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Service: 888-371-4942</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">support</argument>
            </arguments>

      </block> 

      
 </referenceBlock>
```

but i dont know how to manage it from backend.
thank you

Comment: you can create static block in admin and call in xml file.

Comment: You need to create helper file and add both function which I mentioned in answer.

Comment: Did you get output or still you face issue?

Comment: no am still looking for ans

Comment: Did you created helper file and add function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `xsi:type="helper"` and get dynamic value from admin.For that, Follow this below steps for that :

> Replace this code in your xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
           <block class="Learning\Module\Block\Link" name="custom-header-link">
              <arguments>
                 <argument name="label" xsi:type="helper" helper="Learning\Module\Helper\Data::yourFunctionLabel" translate="true"/>
                 <argument name="path" xsi:type="helper" helper="Learning\Module\Helper\Data::yourFunctionPath" translate="true"/>
              </arguments>
           </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now, create **yourFunctionLabel()** and **yourFunctionPath()** in helper file for set dynamic label and path value.

Comment: give me a min will give try again will let you know within a min.

Comment: i have tried it but its not working anyways thanks @rohan

Comment: Can you please post code which you have tried in xml and helper? I tested and then, upload and it's working so.

Comment: Any error or log printed in var folder?

Comment: just tell me one thing how to manage and update  number from backend.

Comment: Create field in system configuration and get value in helper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100898/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-pramod).

Comment: how to share code in comments??

Comment: For more ref : https://bit.ly/33G5ndd

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add 2 methods in `Link.php` file

> Learning\Module\Block\Link.php

and add the method below:

```
public function getLabel()
{
    return "Customer Service: 888-371-4942"; // You can set configuration field data dynamically here
}

public function getPath()
{
    return "Support"; // You can set configuration field data dynamically here
}
```

your layout file code should be

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
    <block class="Learning\Module\Block\Link" name="custom-header-link" />
 </referenceBlock>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: i know how to add links but how to manage that link from backend. thats the issue

Comment: for that you just need to add back-end configuration and use in block. please refer this site : https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-system-xml-configuration-magento-2.html